# Issue with syntax validations for certain scenarios with grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I've written a basic grammar for creating simple expressions (add, mul, div, mod, min, and using functions with some arguments).

Grammar:

```
grammar ExpressionGrammar;

parse: expr EOF;

expr:
    MIN expr
    | expr ( MUL | DIV) expr
    | expr ( ADD | MIN) expr
    | expr  ( MOD )  expr
    | NUM
    | ID
    | STRING
    | function
    | '(' expr ')';

function: ID '(' arguments? ')';

arguments: expr ( ',' expr)*;

/* Tokens */

MUL: '*';
DIV: '/';
MIN: '-';
ADD: '+';
MOD: '%';
OPEN_PAR: '(';
CLOSE_PAR: ')';

NUM: ([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+;
STRING: '"' ~ ["]* '"';
fragment ID_NODE: [a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*;
ID: ID_NODE ('.' ID_NODE)*;
COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;
LINE_COMMENT
    : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;
WS: [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip;
```

Example valid expressions :

```
1. 1+2    - simple add, multiply, divide and mod operations. 
2. "adadfasdf"   -- simply return a string
3. 233.4234234    -- return a number
4. field.value1    -- field is a fieldType on which value exists ( field with multiple values) 
3. SUBSTR("asdfasdf","adsfasdff","asd");   -- a built in function ( such as SUBSTR, ADD, MIN, etc ) which takes arguments. 
4. ABS(field.value1)  
5. ADD( field.value1,field.value2) 
6. MAX( field.value1,field.value3, 2)
7. field.value1 % field.value2

8. It can even span multiple lines 

 ADD(
    field.value1,
    2,
    ABS(field.valu2)   -- can have another function inside this function. 
    )
```

ANTLR is throwing syntax errors  when user inputs a wrong grammar for some scenarios
but the below scenarios are not being shown as errors.

1. It is Allowing multiple closing brackets : `trim(fields.value1))))))))`
2. Allowing multiple expressions without any operators between them (doesn't throw any error when two fields are used without any operator between):

   `field.v1   field.v2`
3. It is also not throwing errors when I have two different expressions in multiple lines (could be an extension to the above scenario).

   ```
    field.v1 + 2
    field.v2 + 3
   ```
4. It is not showing any error when there are multiple closing quotations - `"adfadsfad""""""`

All the above scenarios could be related to a single issue with my grammar? Not sure.

Could anyone help me correct my grammar to catch these errors?

Comment: Are you invoking `parse` or `expr` as your start rule?

Comment: ANTLR will generate methods for all the rules in your grammar. The question is which one you actually call. That is, in your TypeScript code, are you calling `parser.parse()` or `parser.expr()`?

Comment: @sepp2k you are right, I was invoking expr() instead of parse(). my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are classic symptoms of not having an EOF in your invoked rule.

If you don’t include EOF, then ANTLR4 will parse all matching input and quit (before the end of the input stream, if nothing else matches).

In each of your examples, if you look at it as “there’s something valid, followed by invalid input”, you’ll see that they all fit.

This is why @sepp2k asked about which rule you invoked.

It’s pretty clear that you likely invoked the `expr` rule rather than the `parse` rule (since the `parse` rule does have the EOF token included, it would continue to parse until it sees an EOF, and would report errors along the way).

When you generate ANTLR code, it generates methods/functions to start at any rule you want.  There will be some code that you had to write to create an input stream, then create a Lexer from that stream, then create a Parser from the TokenStream you get from the Lexer.  Finally, once, you have the parser object, you’ll choose which parser rule to invoke.

Change that rule from `expr()` to `parse()` and you should start getting the errors you expect.

The EOF in a parser rule, basically, says the entire input must match this rule (i.e. it has to also consume the “END OF FILE” token).  Without that token, the rule can (and will) match anything that matches the rule and stop when it can no longer find valid input.

It’s pretty common to see only a single “top-level” or “entry” rule that ends with EOF.  And that’s generally a clue that it’s the parser rule you call to kick things off.

A couple of exceptions:

- Perhaps you **WANT** to only parse whatever you can match and ignore the rest.  Then use a rule without an terminal EOF.  (This probably rather rare).
- Perhaps you have situations where you know you input should only be an `expr`, but you top level rule is something like `stmts` or `compilationUnit`.  In this situation, you can create a `exprOnly: expr EOF;` rule and then call that rule to parse an expression that will fail unless the entire input matches your syntax for an `expr`.  You’d not have any other rules that reference the `exprOnly` rule, effectively making it a top-level or entry rule.  There’s nothing to prevent you from having multiple top-level rules to choose from.

An EOF in any rule that is referenced by another rule, but expects to match EOF, is likely (almost certainly) a mistake.

Note: no doubt, you will find grammars where the top-level rule does not end with an EOF token.  This is considered a bad practice (for precisely the reason you’ve encountered; it can successfully parse without consuming all the input.

Comment: you are right - I was using expr() instead of parse() which has EOF. Just a quick question here. If I have to add EOF in expr instead of parse() , should I add it after each condition ?    
  `expr:
    MIN expr EOF
    | expr ( MUL | DIV) expr EOF
    | expr ( ADD | MIN) expr EOF
    | expr  ( MOD )  expr EOF
    | NUM EOF
    | ID EOF
    | STRING EOF
     | function EOF`
    | '(' expr ')';  EOF

Comment: @Veryon890 If you do that, you'll never successfully parse an expression with subexpressions. Adding EOF to a production means that it can only be matched at the end of the file, but in the expression `1 + 2` for example, the `1` is not at the end of the file, so you wouldn't want it to have that constraint.

Comment: No, you only want an EOF at the end of a rule that you require to consume the entire input.  EOF is “END OF FILE”.  In your grammar, calling parse() to consume input that should contain an expression (and only and expression), would be the right choice.  Commonly, there is a single “top-level”, or entry rule that ends with an EOF token.  I’ll amend my answer with a bit more on the EOF topic..

Comment: @MikeCargal  @sepp2k  thanks for taking the time to explain me. I understand that parse() has EOF , but if I were to add an EOF to `expr` in the grammar , how should I be doing that? The way I had written in my first comment above doesn't make sense, I understand that. But is there any other way that I can add it to only `expr` and not create a top level rule just for this? I've written a lot of code around `expr` method which generated `ExprContext` for me, but changing it to parse ( which is generating ParseContext ) is a pain with the change in the interface generated .

Comment: @Veryon890 "how should I be doing that?" You shouldn't be doing that is the point. If you add EOF to `expr`, then `expr` can no longer be used anywhere except at the end of file. Since that's not what you want, you shouldn't do that. Obviously I don't know what your code looks like, but I can't imagine replacing every call to `expr` with `parse` and then accessing the expression object of the result would really be such a large effort. In fact if you're making use of listeners and/or visitors, they shouldn't even care whether you pass in `parse()` or `expr()`.